# How to select max price using multiple query

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g

i have create tow table,  table and data inserting value are given below :

> ```
> create table product (
> pid number(10) primary key,
> pname varchar2(30)
> );
>
> INSERT INTO product values(100,'Apple');
> INSERT INTO product values(101,'Banana');
> INSERT INTO product values(102,'Pinaple');
> INSERT INTO product values(103,'Orange');
>
> create table purchase(
> invid  number(10) primary key,
> pid number(10),
> pprice number(10)
> );
> alter table purchase add(constraint pid_fk FOREIGN KEY (pid) references  product(pid));
>
> INSERT INTO  purchase values(10,101,30);
> INSERT INTO  purchase values(11,103,35);
> INSERT INTO  purchase values(12,103,9);
> INSERT INTO  purchase values(13,103,22);
> INSERT INTO  purchase values(14,101,12);
> ```

now i have select table purchase show give data

> ```
> invid    pid  pprice
> 10       101   30
> 11       103   35
> 12       103    9
> 13       103   22
> 14       101   12
> ```

now i want to be last insert price pid=103
now need show  pprice=22
i have all ready done the task using two query  such as:

> `select max(invid) from purchase where pid=103;`

result is 22  and running next statement

> `select max(pprice) from purchase where invid=13;`

show result =22
 i want to show result 22 using  running one statment,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Probably the most direct way is to use a subquery:

```
SELECT MAX(pprice)
FROM purchase
WHERE invid = (SELECT MAX(invid) FROM purchase WHERE pid = 103)
```

Side note, you don't need to `MAX()` `pprice` based on your sample data, but I left it that way in case you need it for your real data set.

Comment: how can i found last price every invid?? and  can be create view?

Comment: @khan `invid` or `pid`?  Looks like `invid` is distinct, so that would just be `SELECT invid, pprice FROM purchase`

Comment: i can add column  with pprice  such as pprice and  pid,invid??

Comment: @khan Based on your sample data, it's easy, just change `SELECT MAX(pprice)` to `SELECT invid, pid, pprice`

Answer (score 0):

The aggregate `FIRST/LAST` function is made exactly for this kind of task. Unfortunately it seems the vast majority of developers don't use it - either because they are not aware of its existence, or because they don't understand how it works, or for who knows what other reason.

https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/functions056.htm

The function allows for the case when the `max(invid)` (in your model) is not unique; in which case you must decide WHICH `pprice` to select. You can select the `max`, or `min`, or average `pprice` (or the `sum` for that matter), from all those that have `pid = 103` and the max value in the `invid` column. Of course, if the `max(invid)` is unique (as it is in your problem), then all these functions will return just the `pprice` associated to that `invid`; but you must still use one of these aggregate functions, since that uniqueness is not known at parsing time, it is only known at execution time. `min` is conventionally used in this manner. So:

```
select min(pprice) keep (dense_rank last order by invid) as pprice
from   ........
where  pid = 103
;
```

Comment: you say right but i need last purchase price for sales,

Comment: @khan - I don't understand what you are trying to say. Did you try what I suggested? If you did, what happened? If you did not, then why not?

Comment: i am happy for your suggest ,but my client want to  sales  from last purchase price , aggregate function is best for max and min, thanks  mathguy

Comment: @khan - OK, so you didn't try what I suggested, because you think it doesn't do what you need. You are wrong; "sales from last purchase" IS an aggregate function, specifically the FIRST/LAST aggregate function. I provided a link to the documentation, where you can see examples - did you even visit that link? Anyway - why do I care? It's your problem, not mine!